# NPAPI Alternative for Legacy Sites?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, npapi

So, Firefox has announced to drop NPAPI support at end of 2016. What would be an alternative for legacy sites?

For example, Google Chrome introduced Chrome Legacy Browser Support (Chrome LBS), that redirects sites using NPAPI technology. A list is maintained with the sites.

Even though, it's little more than a year since Firefox will be doing that, it's never too late to get started on something that effect the web.

Comment: I would imagine the Firefox developers would the best people to answer this type of question.  [The developers have actually spoken on this very topic.](https://blog.mozilla.org/futurereleases/2015/10/08/npapi-plugins-in-firefox/)  Flash will continue to function as an exception.  Java will be addressed within the time frame more then likely.  Silverlight has been discontinued.  The real alternative is to simply use the LTS build of Firefox if you have a continued need for NPAPI add-ons.